# Weird pattern - drawing algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi how can I draw something like this:

https://pastebin.com/6TWZwPzq

from this input:

```
1. 3
2. 4 
3. 1 
4. 2
5. 4
```

where 1 is a first column ,2 is a second.. etc

where

Comment: how is the input related to the output? For this single case the answer is: Write a program that a) takes some input b) ignores the input c) produces your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
  perform a spread process.

Case 2:
  Store into as many string as there are deep, then append into it. Check stringsteam from sstream package